# How do you split a value into multiple rows, and then update it to the same table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have a column called "name" with a cell that has a value "Chazz, Jeremiah".
I'm trying to split it so that "Chazz" and "Jeremiah" have their own row, and then insert that into the original table.

I've used

`SELECT  incident_id, regexp_split_to_table(participant_name, E',') AS name, regexp_split_to_table(participant_gender, E',') AS gender, regexp_split_to_table(participant_age, E',') AS age, INTO participants FROM testing;`

to separate the values, but I had to insert it into a new table.  I was wondering if there was a way for me to separate the multi-valued cells in a table and update it into that same table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "select... into" syntax, use "insert into" instead:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO participants
      SELECT
        incident_id,
        regexp_split_to_table(participant_name, E',') AS name, 
        regexp_split_to_table(participant_gender, E',') AS gender, 
        regexp_split_to_table(participant_age, E',') AS age
      FROM participants;

COMMIT; -- if successful and as expected
ROLLBACK; -- if not!
```

However, I would be careful here with directly inserting these values into the source table. I would make sure to use a transaction so you can ROLLBACK if something doesn't happen as expected.

You will also still have the original "Chazz, Jeremiah" row, which you might need to delete.

Explanation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-selectinto.html
"SELECT INTO creates a new table and fills it with data computed by a query." In other words, "SELECT... INTO" is exclusively for creating new tables - it can't be used the same way as "INSERT".

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-insert.html
"INSERT inserts new rows into a table. One can insert one or more rows specified by value expressions, or zero or more rows resulting from a query."